# Pega o ultimo id gerado no insert com o jquery e redireciona para outra pagina

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, data, load

olá, estou com dificuldade em pegar o id gerado no php com o jquery, para que eu possa assim enviar esse id para outra pagina, segue o codigo:

queryInsert.php

```
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$msg     = $_POST['msg'];

    $query = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tb_tickets (cliente_id,ms_assunto,ms_data,ms_status,ms_read,ms_remetente,ms_destino,ms_mensagem) VALUES (:iduser,:assunto,NOW(),'0','0',:idusers,'1',:msg)");
    $query->bindParam(':iduser', $IdUsuario);
    $query->bindParam(':assunto', $assunto);
    $query->bindParam(':idusers', $IdUsuario);
    $query->bindParam(':msg', $msg);

    if($query->execute()){
        $UltId = $db_con->lastInsertId();
        echo $UltId;
    }else{
        echo 'Error ao solicitar suporte';
    }
```

crudTicket.js

```
$(function () {
    var enviandoForm = false;
    $("#emp-SaveForm").submit(function (e) {
                if (enviandoForm) {
                      return false;
                }
                this.disabled = true;
                enviandoForm = true;
                e.preventDefault();

                var FormData = $(this).serialize(); 

                $.ajax({
                  type: "POST", 
                  url: "queryInsert.php",
                  data: FormData
                 }).done(function (data) {
                    $('#emp-SaveForm').trigger("reset");
                    var notification = new NotificationFx({
                    wrapper : document.body,
                    message : ('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>'),
                    layout : 'growl',
                    effect : 'scale',
                    type : 'notice',
                    ttl : 6000,
                    onClose : function() { return false; },
                    onOpen : function() { return false; }
                    });
                    notification.show();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                     $(".content-loader").fadeOut('slow', function()
                      {
                        $(".content-loader").fadeIn('slow');
                        $(".content-loader").load('add_ms.php?ms='+data);
                        $("#btn-add").hide();
                        $("#btn-view").show();
                       });
                      });
                    }, 1000).always(function() {
                    enviandoForm = false; //Libera o form
                    this.disabled = false;
                });

                return false;
        }); 
});
```

ms_add.php

```
<?php

$msGET = $_GET['ms'];

echo $msGET;
```

[image: Aparece o id e btn-view, porem não aparece o echo...]
Beleza, o que acontece? ele cadastra o ticket na tabela, ele pega o ultimo id, porém ele esse cara `$(".content-loader").load('add_ms.php?ms='+data);` não funciona, já nesse `message : ('<div class="alert alert-info">'+data+'</div>')` me retorna o id normal! desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Faz um `console.log(data);` bem no início do teu done posta o que aparece

Comment: Nenhuma página é carregada em `.content-loader` ou a página `add_ms.php` é carregada, só que sem o valor correto de `ms`?

Comment: @ThiagoSantos, aparece o id normalmente, como a via dito na pergunta!

Comment: então @AndersonCarlosWoss, o btn-add some e o btn-view aparece, parém o echo $_GET['ms']; não me retorna nada, esse echo esta no começo da pagina o resto da pagina tem umas tabelas e etc, que também não aparecem!

Comment: Então aparentemente é falha na requisição e não no valor da *query string*. Seu servidor apresenta algum erro 404 no *log* para o arquivo `add_ms.php`?

Comment: não... olha á img da pagina na pergunta, simplesmente em branco!

Comment: Ok, você editou colocando o nome do arquivo como `ms_add.php` mas o *load* é do arquivo `add_ms.php`. O erro não é esse ou apenas confundiu-se na hora de postar aqui?

Comment: Ele citou o nome do arquivo como `ms_add.php` e no `.load()` colocou `add_ms.php`, foi só erro de escrita ou ta assim mesmo no nome do arquivo e no codigo?

Comment: erro de escrita desculpas! o error persiste!

Comment: testando com o window.location.href='teste2.php?ms='+data; ele funciona! mas preciso mesmo é do load(). teste2.php foi uma pagina que criei e só coloquei echo $_GET['ms'];

Comment: Achei q fosse o `.load()`, não sei se ele faz a interpretação do arquivo php usando esse método. Por isso nao deve estar trazendo resultado. Tente transformar em json o resultado que terá retorno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, para retornar, experimente fazer isso:

```
if ($query->execute()) {
    $UltId = $db_con->lastInsertId();
    echo json_encode(array('id' => $UltId, 'status'=>'1'));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array('id' => $UltId, 'message'=>'Error ao solicitar suporte', 'status'=>'0'));
}
```

E no javascript, capture assim:

```
if (data.status == 1) {
    console.log(data.id);
} else {
    console.log(data.message);
}
```

Comment: Já consigo pegar o id com o $db_con->lastInsertId();, o problema é redirecionar!

Comment: Se tivesse utilizando a API `mysqli`, sim, mas acredito que ele esteja utilizando `PDO`, visto que é `bindParam` na *query*, não `bind_param`, como seria no `mysqli`.

Comment: Valeu pessoal, muito obrigado pela ajuda, eu adicionei o dataType json... e fiz o que o @Ivan publicou e funcionou perfeitamente! mas uma simples pergunta porque só funcionou com o json, ou seja, com o data.id?

Comment: Cara... não sei ao certo... Mas acho que quando vc chamava a pagina usando o `.load()`, o código php não era interpretado pelo servidor. Ou seja, digamos  vc estava tentando fazer que um include de um arquivo php sem que o servidor interpretasse o código.